# How to add a new node into Ignite cluster?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

We’ve an ignite instance(Gridgain) running in the server and would like to add one more node into the same cluster. I used the same config as the current instance but nothing happening after a long wait.I tested the connection with the server by creating a thick client and works well, So I am not sure what is going on?. Please see the screen below

**Running server config**

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="rho-cache"/>
        <property name="consistentId" value="rho-cache"/>
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <!-- Set the size of wal segments to 128MB -->
            <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{128 * 1024 * 1024}"/>

            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                  <!-- Enable perisistence -->
                  <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
               </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="storagePath" value="work"/>
         </bean>
      </property>
      <property name="discoverySpi">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                  <property name="addresses">
                     <list>
                        <value>10.1.8.186</value>
                     </list>
                  </property>
               </bean>
            </property>
         </bean>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

**New Node Config**

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="igniteInstanceName" value="rho-1-cache"/>
        <property name="consistentId" value="rho-1-cache"/>
        <property name="dataStorageConfiguration">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataStorageConfiguration">
            <!-- Set the size of wal segments to 128MB -->
            <property name="walSegmentSize" value="#{128 * 1024 * 1024}"/>

            <property name="defaultDataRegionConfiguration">
               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.DataRegionConfiguration">
                  <!-- Enable perisistence -->
                  <property name="persistenceEnabled" value="true"/>
               </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="storagePath" value="work"/>
         </bean>
      </property>
      <property name="discoverySpi">
         <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
               <bean class="org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.TcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                  <property name="addresses">
                     <list>
                        <value>10.1.8.186</value>
                         <value>195.168.44.88</value>
                     </list>
                  </property>
               </bean>
            </property>
         </bean>
      </property>
   </bean>
```

**Screen when starting the second node**

[image]

Comment: What exception?

Comment: Perfect question which helped me lot. First excpetion was Firewal and that's resolved, second exception was Memory exception and that's also resolved. At last, no exception but nothing happening. I've updated the question with final screen

Comment: Thanks all. Finally cluster is made. The issues were : Firewall (ip address in both side of the system should be unblocked), Antivirus, Memory error.

Comment: @JustinMathew it would be good to put your findings as an answer to your question. This way it'll be easier for people to see the information - not everyone reads the comments. It's also a badge for you I believe ;)